# Cannot get the python test to assert an Exception was thrown

Tags: python, exception, pytest

Code:

```
class ContributionHandler:

    def __init__(self):
        MetricsConfigurator.setup_metrics("ContributionMutationResolverLambda")
        self.entity_linkage_authority_client_factory = EntityLinkageAuthorityClientFactory()
        self.entity_linkage_authority_client = self.entity_linkage_authority_client_factory.get_client()

    @retry(delay=0.5, tries=2)
    def create_contribution(self, input_event):
        """
        Calls Entity Linkage Authority to create a contribution between PEs
        :return: the contribution created
        """

        from_pe = input_event[constants.FROM_PE]
        to_pe = input_event[constants.TO_PE]
        logging.info(f"Creating contribution from PE: {from_pe} to PE: {to_pe}")
        try:
            response = self.__create_contribution_call(input_event)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(f"Error creating the contribution from PE: {from_pe} to PE: {to_pe}")
            raise e

    @retry(delay=0.5, tries=2)
    @metric_time
    @metric_count
    @metric_errors(verbose=True)
    def __create_contribution_call(self, input_event):
        """
        Separate retryable private function for api call with the client.
        """
        relationship_contribution_info = RelationshipContributionInfo(input_event[constants.FROM_PE],
                                                                      input_event[constants.TO_PE], input_event[constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE],
                                                                      input_event[constants.INTENT], input_event[constants.IS_NEGATIVE])
        audit_info = AuditInfo(input_event[constants.AUDIT_INFO][constants.CREATED_BY],
                               input_event[constants.AUDIT_INFO][constants.CREATED_AT])
        try:
            return  self.entity_linkage_authority_client.create_relationship\
                (CreateRelationshipRequest(relationship_contribution_info, audit_info))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info("Recreating the client as Credentials expired1")
            if isinstance(e, ClientError) and e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ExpiredToken':
                logging.info("Recreating the client as Credentials expired2")
                self.entity_linkage_authority_client_factory = EntityLinkageAuthorityClientFactory()
                self.entity_linkage_authority_client = self.entity_linkage_authority_client_factory.get_client()
            raise e
```

**Test case:**

```
@mock.patch(METRICS_IMPORT_PATH + '.setup_metrics')
@mock.patch(ENTITY_LINKAGE_AUTHORITY_CLIENT_FACTORY_IMPORT_PATH + '.get_client')
@mock.patch(ENTITY_LINKAGE_AUTHORITY_CLIENT_FACTORY_IMPORT_PATH + '.__init__')
def test_create_contribution_handler_token_expiry(mock_client_factory_init, mock_get_client, mock_metrics):
    mock_metrics.return_value = None
    mock_client_factory_init.return_value = None
    error_response = {"Error": {"Code": "ExpiredToken"}}
    mock_get_client.return_value.create_relationship(mock.ANY).raiseError.side_effect = ClientError(error_response, "Expired Token")
    contribution_handler = ContributionHandler()

    with pytest.raises(ClientError) :
        contribution_handler.create_contribution(CONTRIBUTION_INPUT)
        # make sure we retried 3 times
       # assert 3 == mock_client_factory_init.call_count
```

***Output:*** 
 Test case is failing with following output:
[CPython36:setup:stdout]         with pytest.raises(ClientError) :
[CPython36:setup:stdout] >           contribution_handler.create_contribution(CONTRIBUTION_INPUT)
[CPython36:setup:stdout] E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE

Comment: Because an exception was **not** raised

Comment: But Im rethrowing the exception in my catch block. Am I missing something?

Comment: Then the `except` block was not reached meaning no exception was raised at all

Comment: Yes. I agree. Thats what the issue is I guess. But I have mocked the client call to throw an exception: mock_get_client.return_value.create_relationship.raiseError.side_effect

Comment: But what is that `raiseError` doing in there? And where is `get_client` being called? You don't seem to be patching the right things at all.

Comment: Ive updated the code under test